# Do I need to use JSON to transfer data from external PHP server to Phonegap iPhone app?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cordova

Do I need to use JSON to transfer data from external PHP server to Phonegap iPhone app? Or can I use a $.get function to pull data from a PHP file?

Thank you for your help in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't, you can use any format you wish except for binary since it comes back as textual data available in `jqXHR` which is a superset of `XMLHttpRequest`, so you can retrieve its `response.responseText` property

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using a php file the echos a string at the end of the code. Then I store this data in javascript variables to place them on a page. Doesnt Apple not allow me to pull that data from an external server?

Comment: Is the problem accessing the XHR? You need to add `EXTERNALHOSTS=*  in `PhoneGap.plist`. Since you're new here, let me remind you to upvote useful answers and to accept an answer if it solved your problem

Comment: There isn't a problem at the moment. My jQuery function can pull my echoed string from my external PHP file. I was just wondering if this was going to break once on Phonegap iPhone because does not allow PHP at all in native apps.

Comment: PhoneGap has no clue what you're using on the server to generate your output, there's no PHP running within the iDevice. It only knows that there's an HTTP response coming back from a server

Answer (score 1):

The point to remember is that PHP is not in your app, it's on your server. You're calling a webservice to get some info, in essence, and no Apple does not put any restriction on this. I've created and released a hybrid app that pulls data from my webservice and displays it in app. No problems.

And you can use any format you want, XML or JSON being most popular

Comment: I know all that, I was just wondering if I could call data from a PHP file without encoding it to JSON. It was easy to encode it with PHP anyway. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.get to retrieve json generated by your php file.

I believe $.get assumes a json response though.

Comment: Answers with "I believe" might as well not be here. Most of the time they contain misinformation. You should answer a question if you know what you're talking about. Guesses are better as comments. `$.get` does not assume JSON